# Can the neurological damage done by alcohol, specifically memory and cognitive performance, be reversed?

Tags: alcohol, marijuana, neuroscience

I read online that heavy alcohol consumption can lead to neurological damage, specifically in areas related to cognitive abilities and memory.

But I haven’t found an article on reversing the damage done to the brain by alcohol and what I want to know if the damage can be reversed.

Articles:

https://www.verywellmind.com/alcohol-damages-day-to-day-memory-function-62982

https://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/arh27-2/186-196.htm

https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2017/12/even-small-amounts-of-alcohol-impair-memory/548474/

Comment: I think this question could be reformatted to a non-personal one, but you would need to show some prior research as well as remove the personal aspects.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the advice,I removed the personal aspects and reformatted the question.

Comment: Great, I do see that you posted this on Psych & Neuro as well, however. Cross-posting is discouraged unless the question really becomes two separate questions on different stacks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Oh, by mistake. I had first posted the question on psych & neuro and then though that it might get more answers if I were to post it on medical sciences but in the process of reposting it on I forgot to delete the original one.

Comment: @crazyfoo Don't delete the question on P&N. It already has an upvoted answer so that question should be kept and this one will remain closed.